# cómo detectar que hay de incompatible en mi app

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

soy nuevo en este tema de ionic, y estoy desarrollando una app usando IONIC1. este es mi escenario, yo estoy desarrollando una app que usa plugins como geolocalización, facebook entre otros y en mi celular que es un samsung galaxy s7, funciona bien. Lo he probado en otros celulares recientes ANDROID,  y funciona.  pero un amigo lo probó en un galaxy note 5 y me dijo que el login con facebok no funcionó, también otro amigo lo probó en un celular huawei con versión 4.4 y tampoco; en este último un mapa que tengo nunca cargó.

Sé como debuggiar y lo hago conectando mi celular que tiene el modo desarrollador para por consola los errores. pero no sé que hacer en el caso de los celulares que no tienen esta opción. también uso herramientas como genymotion para crear máquinas virtuales de alguna versión de android y no funciona porque estas versiones no permiten tener instalado google playstore . Mi aplicación se cierra informando este error. para compilar debí instalar el plugin de google play services, tal vez sea la versión de este el problema, no estoy seguro.

este es mi archivo config.xml.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué estoy haciendo mal? o porque puede ocurrir este problema?

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el error? ¿Podrías añadir un pantallazo?

Comment: @Sema gracias a Dios alguien se interesó por ayudarme. simplemente hago click en un boton de facebook y obtengo mis datos, pero desde estos celulares viejos (tipo 2013 o 2014) ocurre un error, no me redirige a la pantalla que deberia de redirigirme, no estoy seguro cúal es el error.

Comment: Creo que es por la compatibilidad del plugin de facebook, e incluso, podría llegar a darte problemas utilizar a día de hoy Ionic 1 todavía. [Aquí](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/android/README.md) te dan instrucciones de instalación en versiones antiguas y [aquí](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/run-android-platform-error-with-cordova-plugin-facebook4/114510/22) un hilo donde podrías encontrar también una solución. Ya nos cuentas si después de probar eso has tenido suerte o no.

Comment: @Sema gracias por responder, pero segun entiendo los problemas de ellos es en cuanto a la compilada, no cuando estan usando la apicación...

Comment: No se si conoces algun método para hacer debug desde un celular que no tenga modo desarrollador..?

Comment: Pero entonces, si los errores son de compilación, pq dices que "ocurre un error y no redirige a la pantalla que debería", eso es usando la aplicación... ¿Cuándo ocurre entonces el problema? Si es durante la compilación... ¿pq no añades las trazas del error?

Comment: tal vez no me hice entender. yo compilo mi aplicación, y cuando intento autenticarme, sucede  un error, se intenta abrir la ventana de autenticación con facebook y ahi mismo se cierra, en otros casos nisiquiera se abre ese popup

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79253/discussion-between-yavg-and-sema).

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar [Ionic 3](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started). Ya que los plugins se actualizan para las versiones mas recientes de Ionic.
Y por lo de la compatibilidad, puedes probar cambiar el nivel de API en Android Studio, puedes leer sobre eso [Aqui](http://trucosandroidstudio.blogspot.com/2015/03/como-cambiar-nuestro-api-level-de.html).
Te recomiendo usar una API para Android 4.4 en adelante.
y cuando la buildes a la app Ionic, fijate usar el siguiente comando:

`ionic cordova build android --prod`

o

`ionic cordova build android --aot`